# How to get images from instagram with multiple hashtags?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, instagram, hashtag

In my iPhone app, I am trying to get images from **INSTAGRAM** with multiple HASHTAGS. I can able to get images with a single hashtag using following url :

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/CRICKET/media/recent?client_id=API_KEY.

Is there any way to get images with **multiple hashtags** like CRICKET, FOOTBALL at a time instead of making two calls.

Or Is there any out side API's avialble with this feature?

Please help me in this requirements.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say no. An API spec is *entirely* up to the company that owns the website (Instagram). So in order to query two tags, they would have to build that into their server as a feature.

You could create your own intermediary server that your iOS app connects to, however, if you really want just one API call on the iOS device.

iOS -> Your server -> makes two calls, one for each tag -> Instagram's server

Comment: Thanks brimizer. Is there any out side API's avialble with this feature?

Comment: Now that's a good question! I don't know. There may be a website that can do this... but I doubt it because API require access keys and it's difficult to customize a middleman server. It wouldn't be hard to roll your own, really. Try Ruby Sinatra or another really lightweight server.